# Angular 2 in VS2015 - best practice

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2015

I would like to ask you a question about best practice in creation of Angular 2 App. My plan is to create two projects in one solution, first one will be for Web Services (ASP.NET) and second one for Client (Angular 2 with TS). I would like to ask you what types of templates should I use for these projects. Any other concerns / suggestions are really welcome.

Comment: This may help https://youtu.be/HAjUJOc7yW4

Comment: Consider the answer to what I wrote here in response to a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311639/typescript-in-vs-2015-asp-net-4-mvc-5-what-are-the-working-combinations-of-set/42312822#42312822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested having one solution is good but one bottleneck is Angular 2 as SPA should be used with ASP.NET Core. If you want to use with MVC 5 or before, its less productive work.

I would suggest that Web API can be either ASP.NET Core Web API or Web API 2 but Angular 2 project should follow be ASP.NET Core with Angular 2 SPA.

This link serves the purpose http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/

Also there is detail video on live.asp.net about this.

Comment: Hi Mithun, thanks for reply. Unfortunately I'm starting with web developing, originally I'm C# WinApp developer. Can you explain to me what does it mean SPA?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I found myself. I will try the link you've posted and if it will help, I will mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: SPA means Single Page Application which doesn't refresh page. It acts like desktop app but originally they are web apps.

Comment: yeah, I already found out :) Sorry, I'm not familiar with some abbreviations or terms, so sometimes it is hard for me to understand what exactly was ment by... what should I exactly do... in web app dev I'm beginner. Currently I'm installing according to the link you have posted. I will let you know as soon as it is done.

Comment: Mithun, it worked! That was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Comment: I disagree strongly with this answer. It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever that the technology that powers the JSON API which your SPA talks to should impact the architecture of your SPA or vice versa. Your WebAPI could be written in PHP and your SPA in React for all neither should care. By coupling a server side technology to your SPA you introduce tooling rigidity, and potential difficulties for team members working on unrelated portions of your system, for absolutely no (zero) benefit.